# CORS error Header Allow-Origin * http vs https

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am using an XMLHttpRequest(), sending a `POST`.
In our servlets, we default to, `req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Safari & Edge result in CORS error if it's served from `http://`, but not if `https://`.  Chrome & FF behave ok regardless.

I have a 2nd POST for uploads which runs successfully because it includes this method:

```
setSecureConnection: function() {
  baseURL = baseURL.replace(/http\:/, 'https:');
}
```

On the servlet that fails, I have tried `req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("Origin"));` as well without success.

So why does the browser not accept the wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use CORSA API (saves the headache of having to deal with headers) by appending https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ to the URL (eg: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://URL2POST.COM/); just a helpful tip.

As for your headers, for Edge & Safari assuming your request is passing the origin and everything is proper you might want to try the following:

```
req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If");
req.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DAV, content-length, Allow");
```

Hope it helps :)